# Create a function to calculate Bayes Probability in R

Tags: r, dataframe, probability, bayesian

I'm working on a project and i need to create a function in R to calculate the following probability :

P(Y|X) = P(Y and X) / P(X)

by using table and prop.table

Any idea please.

Answer (score 1):

You can try something like this:

**STEP 1**: define two factors:

```
x <- factor(sample(5, 200, replace = TRUE))
y <- cut(rnorm(200, 20, 10), breaks = c(-Inf, 0, 10, 20, 30, 40, Inf))
```

**STEP 2**: define function which will calculate contingency table for for `x` and `(x,y)` and which will return function that calculates conditional probability.

This way you will only need to calculate contingency tables once for given factors and not every time you want to calculate conditional probability on same pair of factors.

```
conditionalProb <- function(fact1, fact2){
  
  if(!is.factor(fact1) || !is.factor(fact2)) stop("factors are required")
  if(length(fact1) != length(fact2)) stop("same length required")
  
  table_fact1 <- table(fact1)
  table_fact12 <- table(fact1, fact2) 
  
  function(x, y){
    
    x_ind <- which(rownames(table_fact12) == x)
    y_ind <- which(colnames(table_fact12) == y)
    
    if(length(x_ind) == 0 || length(y_ind) == 0) 
      stop("Provide correct values for variables")
    
    denominator <- table_fact1[x_ind]
    if(denominator == 0) return(0)
    
    unname(table_fact12[x_ind, y_ind] / denominator)
  }
}
```

**STEP 3**: for given factors calculate conditional probability function:

```
myProb <- conditionalProb(x, y)
```

`myProb` is function that takes value of `x` and `y` and calculates `P(y|x)`

**STEP 4**: calculate some conditional probabilities:

```
myProb("1", "(20,30]")
```

**Note**:

Possible values for first argument are: `levels(x)`. Possible values for second argument are: `levels(y)`

Comment: thank you for you response you save me a lot of time